# Laravel 4 Task Scheduling not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, scheduled-tasks

I am using laravel 4 and I want to use the Task Scheduling I have found at https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#introduction but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
user@ASUS c:\xampp\htdocs\ski\theskitrip\protected
# php artisan schedule:run



  [InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "schedule" namespace.




user@ASUS c:\xampp\htdocs\ski\theskitrip\protected
```

I just wondering because I have followed in the document, I create the `.../app/Console/Kernel.php` and this is the content of `Kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
           DB::table('tb_applicants')->insert(array('fullname' => "Mar Binay", 'email' => "asdsad@sdfsdf.dsf"));
        })->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

does anyone have an idea about my case? I don't want to use cron because it quite tricky.

Question, is it need to create the schedule in php artisan similar to this? https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan

Comment: Those errors don't look to have any relevance to your scheduled task.  They are HTTP request errors.  Did you run the schedule with artisan?

Comment: I got confused about this. I will revise my question

Comment: Laravel 4 doesn't have the `schedule:run` command.  When referring to the docs, make sure you select 4.2 and not master.  Master is referring to the latest builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Scheduling is available from Laravel 5 so if you're writing that you are using Laravel 4 - it won't work at all!

Also `.../app/Console/Kernel.php` - LAravel 4 does not support this file yet.